# Do minors need parental permission to fly with a private pilot?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, passenger

I’m a 17 year old private pilot, and my friend and his girlfriend who are also 17 want to fly with me. It’s not clear whether they are asking their parents permission. If their parents didn’t want them to go and find out, would I, the pilot, get in trouble? Are there any regulations regarding this subject? Should I get their parents written consent before taking them flying?  This question pertains specifically to the United States.

Comment: The answer to your question entirely depends on where in the world you are.

Comment: It would be in the US

Comment: Please note that we can only answer about **aviation regulations** (FAA in this case) on this site. There might be other laws and regulations about transporting minors. Questions about such local laws should be asked on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It probably also (or only) depends on the law of your state.

Comment: It very likely (for state law) also matters whether you'll be landing back where you took off, or somewhere else in the same or another state -- and in the latter case, might depend on what the minor couple get up to after landing (or during the flight).

Comment: Someone needs to edit to say "In the US"  ---

Comment: @quietflyer I added the [faa-regulations] tag based on OP's comment above. IMHO there is no need for spelling it out in the question. If you think differently, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: @Bianfable -- since anyone can edit tags, I think it's best that the question be self-sufficient independent of whatever tags are attached-- editing--

Comment: In the state of California, it's technically considered kidnapping to transport a minor across *county* lines against their parents' permission.

Comment: @Phil Miller, "against parent's wishes", or "without parent's permission"?  Those are two very different legal standards.  And FWIW, if all parties are minors it is likely different than if one is over 18.  Things get messy when a 17 year old "child" and their best friend who is a week older at 18 (and therefore an "adult") get into a legal scrape...

Comment: I assume you are not the estranged partner of the other parent of one of the minors, and your route is not crossing national borders ;-).

Answer (score 14):

There’s no FAA regulation requiring that. That being said, if your passengers are minors, their parents have the ultimate say as to what they can and cannot do.  It would be wise to make sure that your friends have permission from their parents for the activity prior to taking them as passengers.

Comment: Sorry for taking this off tangent, but I just had to express my bemusement by your implication that parents have any real say about what their 17 year old kids can and cannot do ;)

Comment: @yoniLavi Legally they do, and the person transporting them without permission (by any means) can be in serious legal trouble.  But this is a (complicated) legal question and that is why the question would be better asked at https://law.stackechange.com.

Comment: Well they do.  And unless there is a compelling state interest otherwise, the authorities will side with the parents.

Comment: @RBarryYoung really? So a 17 year old who boards a bus when forbidden to do so by his parents could get the bus driver into trouble? On the metro? An uber driver? So how is a private pilot different?

Comment: @abligh Seems like the difference would be that a bus driver has no knowledge of that, and no expectation to need to know, whereas the private pilot very obviously does know since they're asking about it here :p

Comment: @abligh The difference is not the means of transportation but the circumstances of travel, the relationship between the parties, and the relative ordinariness or unusualness of the circumstances. It's also almost definitely going to be a requirement of either whoever you are renting the plane from and/or your insurance.

Comment: Remember, the pilot is 17 also!  High school friends ride together in cars all the time, what is different about an airplane?

Comment: If the parents explicitly forbid the activity and you go against their wishes and take their child flying, you can be in big trouble for that

Comment: @abligh as I said "*can be*", yes, depending on the jurisdiction, the circumstances and their knowledge of the situation.  *It's complicated*.

Answer (score 10):

If you are asking about *FAA regulations*, the answer is "no, there are no regulations on this subject".  I've been involved in *EAA Young Eagle Rides*, *CAP glider encampments*, etc, and if there had been any FAA regulations bearing on a requirement for obtaining parental permission before giving young people rides in aircraft, someone would have mentioned it at some point.  Not to suggest that parental permission wasn't obtained anyway, for other reasons-- but a specific FAA regulation on the subject would surely have been mentioned if it existed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need their parents explicit consent anymore then you would to give them a lift in your car, but you do need to ensure you are legally covered. As PiC you have legal responsibilities and liabilities so before you can take on the risks associated with carrying passengers you should check with whomever would be sued if they got hurt. If you are legally a minor, that would be your parents and/or whoever pays your insurance premiums.
Also be a little careful about crossing state lines, as the laws relating to transporting minors over state lines vary from state to state and can be quite surprising.